# Highcharts - allowPointDrilldown: false not hiding category names

Tags: highcharts

allowPointDrilldown: false not hiding category names.

1. Drill down to second level
2. Unselect Parent and Child2 or any combination. The category names are     not hiding and also unwanted sequence numbers are also showing. (-1, 8, 9).

How to hide the unwanted category names?

`jsfiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/4gdwjkn4/

Comment: Honestly I cannot replicate that, I hide Parent and Child2 series from legend, and then drill into child1. As a result I see two cols with two categories without extra labels.

Comment: To replicate, open the jsfiddle link. After it is opened, do not hide Parent and Child2. Do a drill down, now you could be able to see 8 columns then hide Parent and Child2 or any combination.

Comment: Let me know what is wrong, because this is default behaviour, if you need to disable tat you should switch allowPointDrilldown param as true value.